# GAE python upload pictures(blob) with other information

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have input="text" and input="file"

I want to upload picture with description.

There are some problem... to upload picture... I need to use blobhandler.
to upload text fields... I need to use webapp2.RequestHandler

Is it possible to upload both blob and text at once?
How can i upload both blob and text at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a closer look at the [demo app](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Complete_sample_application) in the blobstore doc. The URL you pass to `create_upload_url` gets POSTed to after the blob (file) upload is complete. The original form fields are passed through.